# Mysterious Line Break between divs. JSFiddle included

Tags: html, css, space, spacing

was working on a websites design and for some reason, there is a linebreak between 2 divs that really shouldn't exist.  Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d593fdea/

I know the design is ugly right now, but ignore most of it.  My question only has to do with the gap between the div offersContainer and recentWinnersHeadlineContainer.

It is really bugging me because that gap shouldn't exist and I have no clue why it does.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">

<div id="navContainer">
<div id="logoImgContainer"><img src="logo.png"></div>
<p id="navLinks">Prizes Winners FAQ Contact Us</p>
</div>

<div id="slideShowContainer">
<img src="slide1.jpg">
</div>

<div id="offersContainer">
<div class="offersArrowImg">
<img src="leftOffersArrow.jpg">
</div>
<div class="offerContainer">
<img class="offerImg" src="offer1.jpg">
<div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
</div>
<div class="offerContainer">
<img class="offerImg" src="offer2.jpg">
<div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
</div>
<div class="offerContainer">
<img class="offerImg" src="offer3.jpg">
<div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
</div>
<div class="offerContainer">
<img class="offerImg" src="offer4.jpg">
<div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
</div>
<div class="offersArrowImg">
<img src="rightOffersArrow.jpg">
</div>
</div>

<div id="recentWinnersHeadlineContainer">
<p id="recentWinnersHeadline">Recent Winners</p>
</div>

<div id="recentWinnersContainer">
<div class="recentWinnerContainer">
<img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner1.jpg">
<p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
</div>
<div class="recentWinnerContainer">
<img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner2.jpg">
<p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
</div>
<div class="recentWinnerContainer">
<img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner3.jpg">
<p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
</div>
<div class="recentWinnerContainer">
<img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner4.jpg">
<p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
</div>
<div class="recentWinnerContainer">
<img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner5.jpg">
<p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="recentWinnersMapContainer">

</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#mainContainer {
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#navContainer {
width:1000px;
height:75px;
background-color:#3299bb;
}

#logoImgContainer {
float:left;
margin:13px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#navLinks {
float:right;
margin: 15px 20px 0 0;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
font-size:30px;
color:#ffffff;
}

#slideShowContainer {
width:1000px;
height:380px;
background-color:#000000;
}

#offersContainer {
width:1000px;
height:188px;
background-color:blue;
}

.offerContainer {
width:227px;
height:188px;
float:left;
background-color:red;
}

#offerImg {
width:227px;
height:146px;
}

.offersArrowImg {
float:left;
}

#recentWinnersHeadlineContainer {
width:1000px;
height:60px;
background-color:#ff9900;
}

#recentWinnersContainer {
width:495px;
height:320px;
}
```

Comment: BTW I know some of the code may have been unnecessary to share, but wanted to include everything because I might overlook something important if I don't post it all.  And yes, I know the websites layout isn't finished, just want to get this question solved before I finish the rest of the CSS.

Comment: dont worry about it dude, the only people on here that are going to criticize you for how your site looks or is coded in its test stages are pretentious a-holes anyways.

Comment: I know you've already gotten an answer, but you really would benefit from indenting your markup and styling. You actually have an extra closing div tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `margin-top` property for the contained `<p>` element.

You need to add this code:

```
#recentWinnersHeadlineContainer p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Here's your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/d593fdea/1/

Comment: I haven't set the margin for the p element recentWinnersHeadline.  It's not even in the CSS yet, because I didn't get to it since this weird spacing problem showed up.  I will try adding it and setting it to 0 and see if that fixes it for some odd reason.

Comment: That actually fixed it, I guess there was a default margin I wasn't aware of.  I hope you can understand why that mystery margin confused me, thanks so much :D  I will select this as the answer when stackoverflow let's me in 7 minutes.

Comment: Happy to help! Browser default adds 1.0em of margin to top and bottom of `<p>` elements. You could use a reset/normalize stylesheet to prevent this, but in your case it's probably best to just adjust that one particular element. Just be cautious that ALL contained `<p>` elements will have no margin-top, so it might affect your layout if you add more `<p>`s in #recentWinnersHeadlineContainer

Comment: Awesome, good information.  Btw, what if I want to actually add a margin-top to the <p> recentWinnersHeadline?  Should I just add padding to it's container div instead?

Comment: @DavidStampher: precisely. `padding-top` to the `<div>` or the `<p>` either way is a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

it's the default margin on the `p` tag, in the future you should either use a reset or just globally clear margin and padding from all elements

```
#recentWinnersHeadline{
  margin: 0;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d593fdea/2/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, that default margin caused some confusion for me.  Lesson learned :)  Btw, how do I use a reset?  Is that some css?

Comment: yeah its just a file that you can download and add to your site. Here are some common ones: [http://www.cssreset.com/](http://www.cssreset.com/). Personally I don't use them. I think they're a bit of an overkill but some people swear by them. I just use: `*{margin:0;padding:0;}` which kills the defaults on every element you write. Then you can set the margin and/or padding to what you want. That does the trick for me.

Comment: Great, I will do that from now on :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has already been solved, but this is another problem:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="navContainer">
        <div id="logoImgContainer"><img src="logo.png"></div>
        <p id="navLinks">Prizes Winners FAQ Contact Us</p>
    </div>

    <div id="slideShowContainer">
        <img src="slide1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="offersContainer">
        <div class="offersArrowImg">
        <img src="leftOffersArrow.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="offerContainer">
        <img class="offerImg" src="offer1.jpg">
        <div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
    </div>

    <div class="offerContainer">
        <img class="offerImg" src="offer2.jpg">
        <div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
    </div>

    <div class="offerContainer">
        <img class="offerImg" src="offer3.jpg">
        <div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
    </div>

    <div class="offerContainer">
        <img class="offerImg" src="offer4.jpg">
        div class="offerBtn">Offer Name</div>
    </div>

    <div class="offersArrowImg">
        <img src="rightOffersArrow.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="recentWinnersHeadlineContainer">
    <p id="recentWinnersHeadline">Recent Winners</p>
</div>

<div id="recentWinnersContainer">
    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
        <img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner1.jpg">
        <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>

    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
        <img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner2.jpg">
        <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>

    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
        <img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner3.jpg">
        <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>

    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
        <img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner4.jpg">
        <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>

    <div class="recentWinnerContainer">
        <img class="recentWinnerImg" src="recentWinner5.jpg">
        <p class="recentWinnerName">Firstname Lastname</p> entered to win a <p class="recentWinnerPrizeName">Prize Name</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="recentWinnersMapContainer">

</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

^Notice that the last closing div tag has no matching opening counterpart. This is very obvious with indenting. It is impossible to see without.

Comment: Ah thank you, I appreciate that.  The last closing tag is supposed to be for mainContainer, guess I accidentally put it after the 2nd offersArrowImg container. 

I will clean up the code with indents before I actually go live with the site for sure.

Comment: Actually the last closing div tag is the closing tag for mainContainer.

Comment: @David Stampher I understand that it's supposed to be the closing tag for mainContainer, but currently the closing tag for mainContainer is just before the recentWinndersHeadlineContainer div. I've indented it twice now and each time that's where it gets closed using your markup.